# Show the summary from functions results JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have inputs to choose the amount of buying different tickets (normal and with discount) for different exhibitions.
These inputs for one exhibition look like this:

```
<input type="number" class="count" value="0" min="1" max="10" id="inputNumberSelect-light" oninput="priceLight()">
<input type="number" class="count ml-3" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="inputNumberDiscSelect-light" oninput="priceLightDisc()">
```

I calculate each price from each input separately with a help of functions:

```
function priceLight() {
    let amount_light = document.getElementById("inputNumberSelect-light").value;
    let price_light = 40;
    let total_light = amount_light * price_light;
    document.getElementById("price__light_total").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light + " zł";        
};
 function priceLightDisc() {
    let amount_light_disc = document.getElementById("inputNumberDiscSelect-light").value;
    let price_light_disc = 35;
    let total_light_disc = amount_light_disc * price_light_disc;
    document.getElementById("price__light_total_disc").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light_disc + " zł";
};
```

The price for each type of ticket is displayed in a `<span>` with a related id.
Before the next step, all worked correctly.

Then I need to make a summary which I need to display in a table with other information related to the order.
The place for displaying total price is related to  with an id:

```
<td id="show__price_total"></td>
```

There I've faced the problem with a total price which is a summary of `priceLight()` and `priceLightDisc()`.

I've tried to return results from each function and then to sum them, so it looked:

```
function priceLight() {
        let amount_light = document.getElementById("inputNumberSelect-light").value;
        let price_light = 40;
        let total_light = amount_light * price_light;
        document.getElementById("price__light_total").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light + " zł";
        let resultLight = total_light; //new lines
        return resultLight; //new lines
    };
 function priceLightDisc() {
        let amount_light_disc = document.getElementById("inputNumberDiscSelect-light").value;
        let price_light_disc = 35;
        let total_light_disc = amount_light_disc * price_light_disc;
        document.getElementById("price__light_total_disc").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light_disc + " zł";
        let resultLight = total_light_disc; //new lines
        return resultLight; //new lines
    };
function resultLight(){
    let result = (+priceLight()) + (+priceLightDisc());
    document.getElementById("show__price_total").innerHTML = result;
    return result;     
}
```

In `console.log(resultLight())` it shows the result correctly (also not a string but a number), but the result is not displayed. How to display a summary of 2 functions correctly and to be this total price dynamic?

Also, there is 1 more concern, but a bit smaller:

1. How to make it possible to choose not more than 10 tickets per one exhibition from 2 inputs? Now it's possible to choose 10 tickets from both inputs, but I need to make it not more than 10 in total.

I will be grateful for every helpful comment. Thank you in advance for every reply!

I've added a snippet, hope it will be clear with this.

P.S. Js code is not optimized, because I've just started learning JavaScript.

```js
/*Exhibition price count*/
function priceLight() {
        let amount_light = document.getElementById("inputNumberSelect-light").value;
        let price_light = 40;
        let total_light = amount_light * price_light;
        document.getElementById("price__light_total").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light + " zł";
        let resultLight = total_light;
        return resultLight;
    };
function priceLightDisc() {
        let amount_light_disc = document.getElementById("inputNumberDiscSelect-light").value;
        let price_light_disc = 35;
        let total_light_disc = amount_light_disc * price_light_disc;
        document.getElementById("price__light_total_disc").innerHTML = "Price: " + total_light_disc + " zł";
        let resultLight = total_light_disc;
        return resultLight;
    };
function priceDark() {
        let amount_dark = document.getElementById("inputNumberSelect-dark").value;
        let price_dark = 30;
        let total_dark = amount_dark * price_dark;
        document.getElementById("price__dark_total").innerHTML = "Wartość: " + total_dark + " zł";
    };
function priceDarkDisc() {
        let amount_dark_disc = document.getElementById("inputNumberDiscSelect-dark").value;
        let price_dark_disc = 25;
        let total_dark_disc = amount_dark_disc * price_dark_disc;
        document.getElementById("price__dark_total_disc").innerHTML = "Wartość: " + total_dark_disc + " zł";
    };
function priceBoth() {
        let amount_both = document.getElementById("inputNumberSelect-both").value;
        let price_both = 60;
        let total_both = amount_both * price_both;
        document.getElementById("price__both_total").innerHTML = "Wartość: " + total_both + " zł";
    };
function priceBothDisc() {
        let amount_both_disc = document.getElementById("inputNumberDiscSelect-both").value;
        let price_both_disc = 50;
        let total_both_disc = amount_both_disc * price_both_disc;
        document.getElementById("price__both_total_disc").innerHTML = "Wartość: " + total_both_disc + " zł";
    };
    
/*Summary*/
function resultLight(){
    let result = (+priceLight()) + (+priceLightDisc());
    document.getElementById("show__price_total").innerHTML = result;
    return result;        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Bilety</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section__choice py-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="py-4 section__number_people">
                <h2>Tickets</h2>
                <!--tickets-light-->
                <div class="section__number_qty py-3" id="tickets__light_qty">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label for="inputNumberSelect">Amount of tickets</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count" value="0" min="1" max="10" id="inputNumberSelect-light" oninput="priceLight()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>40</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                 <span id="price__light_total" class="numeric_value"></span> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">  
                            <label for="inputNumberDiscSelect">Amount of tickets with discount</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count ml-3" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="inputNumberDiscSelect-light" oninput="priceLightDisc()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>35</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                 <span id="price__light_total_disc" class="numeric_value"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--tickets-dark-->
                <div class="section__number_qty py-3" id="tickets__dark_qty">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label for="inputNumberSelect">Amount of tickets</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count" name="Quantity_visitors" value="0" min="1" max="8" id="inputNumberSelect-dark" oninput="priceDark()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>30</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                 <span id="price__dark_total"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">  
                            <label for="inputNumberDiscSelect">Amount of tickets with discount</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count ml-3" name="Quantity_visitors_disc" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="inputNumberDiscSelect-dark" oninput="priceDarkDisc()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>25</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                <span id="price__dark_total_disc"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--tickets-both-->
                <div class="section__number_qty py-3" id="tickets__both_qty">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <label for="inputNumberSelect">Amount of tickets</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count" name="Quantity_visitors" value="0" min="1" max="10" id="inputNumberSelect-both" oninput="priceBoth()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>60</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                <span id="price__both_total"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">  
                            <label for="inputNumberDiscSelect">Amount of tickets with discount</label>
                            <input type="number" class="count ml-3" name="Quantity_visitors_disc" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="inputNumberDiscSelect-both" oninput="priceBothDisc()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Price per ticket: 
                            <span>50</span>
                            zł
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>
                                <span id="price__both_total_disc"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container section__summary_options py-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="summary__data">
                    <h2 class="summary__title pb-3">
                        Summary:
                    </h2>
                    <table class="table table-dark py-3">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Date</th>
                          <th scope="col">Exh</th>
                          <th scope="col">Lang</th>
                          <th scope="col">Normal tickets</th>
                          <th scope="col">Tickets with disc</th>
                          <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th id="show__date"></th>
                          <td id="show__exh"></td>
                          <td id="show__language"></td>
                          <td id="show__number"></td>
                          <td id="show__number_disc"></td>
                          <td id="show__price_total"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, in only one place it should be displayed summary from only one of 3 exhibitions depending on which exhibition visitor is going to buy a ticker. So in `<td id="show__price_total"></td> ` there's should be the price from `resultLight()` OR `resultDark()` or `resultBoth()`. But I'm not sure if it's possible with only one id. Probably I need to create 3 different tables with different id. But I think it can be done somehow easily.

Comment: What if you updated the summary from those functions?

Comment: Also, as a side note, there are duplicate ID's in your html

Comment: @trentHarlem If I change the number of chosen tickets the price updates and in console result from the function  `resultLight()` also updates each time I call it.

Comment: @trentHarlem where's exactly? if you're about inputs `inputNumberDiscSelect-light` and `inputNumberSelect-light` they are different. Where are the same ID's? Will be grateful for this comment

Comment: duplicate id... "price__light"

Comment: check  resultLight(). you have code after the return

Comment: I took another look at it and dont see the console.log you mentioned. Maybe your snippet needs to be updated?  I made a fiddle that might give you an idea. https://jsfiddle.net/trentHarlem/wgv0bdeh/7/  (user rep prevented move to chat)